# is it possible to pass a function as a parameter into another function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am defined a const function in react like this:

```
const LazyOptions = () => {
  return <Cascader options={options} loadData={loadData} onChange={onChange} changeOnSelect />;
};
```

now I define the onChange in the outer function and pass it into this `LazyOptions` function:

```
    const onChange = (value, selectedOptions) => {
      var unique = value.filter(onlyUnique);
      this.setState({
        formValues:{
          province: unique.toString()
        }
      });
    };

    LazyOptions(onChange)
```

but it shows error:

```
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

what should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set the prop in `LazyOption` onchange Handler like that

```js
const LazyOptions = ({onChangeHandler}) => {
  return <Cascader options={options} loadData={loadData} onChange={onChangeHandler} changeOnSelect />;
};
```

and in your parent component pass that function it will work well

```js
    const onChange = (value, selectedOptions) => {
      var unique = value.filter(onlyUnique);
      this.setState({
        formValues:{
          province: unique.toString()
        }
      });
    };

    return <LazyOptions onChangeHandler={onChange} />
```